# Bad review audit

Tags: support

Reviews this question https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/208957  and attempted to flag the question.  Popup indicated I had flagged this reply already but do not believe I did. Closed window and clicked I'm Done and received the Stop and pay attention warning.

This was a bad reply and I attempted to flag as such but system would not allow.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You previously flagged this answer as "very low quality" (and were not the only one to do so) and it was subsequently deleted by another moderator.

The review has it recorded as "No Action Needed", which of course would cause you to fail the review audit. Are you sure you clicked "I'm Done"?

Comment: Hmmm  Perhaps I mis-clicked thinking that No Action was correct as it would not permit a flag.  I did think I clicked I'M done but...   Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Seeing that you've already flagged something is a good indicator of a review audit. Remember also that other actions such as downvoting would also have allowed you to pass the audit.